# Delete outdated entries in a hash and keep only one latest key value pair

Tags: perl

I have a requirement where in i need to delete old entries in a hashref. For e.g. in the below data section only "2017/06/28" key value pair should survive.
Rest all key value pairs should be deleted. Please provide me ideas how to accomplish this.

**DATA**

```
$data_hashref = {
          '2017/06/27' => {
                            'start' => '13:07:00',
                            'end' => '23:47:00'
                          },
          '2017/06/15' => {
                            'start' => '07:11:00',
                            'end' => '00:18:00'
                          },
          '2017/06/28' => {
                            'end' => '06:37:00',
                            'start' => '00:06:00'
                          },
          '2017/06/17' => {
                            'start' => '09:17:00',
                            'end' => '10:17:00'
                          }
        };
```

**RESULT**

```
$data_hashref = {
          '2017/06/28' => {
                            'end' => '06:37:00',
                            'start' => '00:06:00'
                          }
        };
```

Comment: What code have you tried to solve this problem? SO isn't a code-writing service, and shouldn't be treated as such. It's for specific programming problems, where you show the particular code you're having problems with, and you get help based on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $href = {
          '2017/06/27' => {
                            'start' => '13:07:00',
                            'end' => '23:47:00'
                          },
          '2017/06/15' => {
                            'start' => '07:11:00',
                            'end' => '00:18:00'
                          },
          '2017/06/28' => {
                            'end' => '06:37:00',
                            'start' => '00:06:00'
                          },
          '2017/06/17' => {
                            'start' => '09:17:00',
                            'end' => '10:17:00'
                          }
};

my (undef, @keys) = sort {$b cmp $a} keys %$href;

delete @$href{ @keys };

use Data::Dumper; print Dumper $href;
```

Update: stevieb is correct in his comments about this post. I'll try to explain what I did.

The date format goes from largest part to the smallest, (`YYYY/MM/DD`). So, it can be sorted with a ordinary ascii sort, `cmp`.

It is sorted from the latest date to the earliest date. The sort result is assigned to `undef` and `@keys`. The latest date then will be assigned to `undef` and the remaining keys (to be deleted) are assigned to `@keys`.

The `delete` deletes all the earlier dates and their values from the hash using a hash slice, `@$href{ @keys }`, leaving only the latest date and its value, a hash reference.

Comment: I don't think that responding to questions where the OP doesn't put in any effort is helpful, especially when you haven't clarified at all what your code does. Essentially, this code-only answer doesn't explain anything to the OP, nor future readers.

Answer (score 1):

Just find the one you want to keep, and assign it to the hash.

```
use List::Util qw( maxstr );

my $newest = maxstr keys %$href;

%$href = ( $newest => $href->{$newest} );
```

It's a little more efficient to find the newest key than to sort all the keys (O(N) vs O(N log N)), and no more complicated.